# How can Zaremba's Conjecture be true if it fails for $d=1$?

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

In the following photo is the definition of some sets and the conjecture of Zaremba. Am I missing something obvious or does the conjecture not certainly fail as $d=1$ will never be in the set $\mathfrak{D}_{\{1,\ldots,A\}}$?

The are no options $b$ as a numerator for $d=1$ that satisfy $0<b<1$.

[image]

Comment: I changed photo as there was an error in the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoted text appears to come from [*On Zaremba's conjecture*](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v180-n1-p03-s.pdf) by Jean Borgain and Alex Kontorovich.

The authors consider continued fraction representations of elements of $(0,1)$, which, I guess, is to allow them to assume the form
$$
\frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{a_3+\frac{1}{\ldots}}}},
$$
that is, a form with integer term $a_0$ equal to $0$ (as they specify just prior to the quoted passage). Neglecting $a_0$ enables them to avoid having to allow a $0$ into their alphabet that will only ever be used as the first partial quotient.

As you noticed, with this setup their statement fails for denominator $1$. The easiest fix is simply to modify the conjecture to state that every integer *greater* than $1$ occurs as the denominator of an element of $\mathfrak{R}_\mathcal{A}$. An alternative fix would be to allow $b=0$ (which would correspond to the sequence $[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k]$ being empty, that is, to $k=0$). Then the conjecture can be left as is.

For more information about this problem, see [A141822](https://oeis.org/A141822) in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer sequences (OEIS). Note that the OEIS sequence starts with denominator $2$; they don't bother worrying about denominator $1$.

Comment: I've edited my post to remove some irrelevant guesses that didn't really make sense. In particular, the non-uniqueness of the continued fraction applies to all rational numbers, not just integers (but can be eliminated by forbidding the last partial quotient to equal $1$).